# php generating csv file only works first time

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I've the following script:

```
<?php
//Define basepath for codeigniter
define('BASEPATH', '/');

//Include constants.php config file from codeigniter
require_once "../../my_manager/system/application/config/constants.php";

//Check username and password from GET
if( $_GET['username'] != IMPORT_USERNAME || $_GET['password'] != IMPORT_PASSWORD )
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Denied Access";
    return; 
}

//running scripts
include 'export_table1.php';
include 'export_table2.php';
include 'export_table3.php';
include 'export_table4.php';
?>
```

Eache export is like the following:

```
<?php
//$host="localhost";
$host="";
$user="";
$pass="";
$db_name="";
$table="table1";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name) or die("Connection Error");

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("sql error");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$csv = "";

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$delim = "";
//retrieving first line fields
foreach($row as $k => $v)
{
$csv .= $delim . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $k) . '"';
$delim= ";";
}
$csv .= "\n";

//retrieving value into fields
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$delim = "";
foreach($row as $v)
{
$csv .= $delim . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $v) . '"';
$delim = ";";
}
$csv .= "\n";

}
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$table.".csv");
echo $csv;
exit
}
else
{
echo "No records";
}
 exit

?>
```

The issue is that only the first script is fired, so I can get only the first table downloaded into csv file. If I launch first the table2 export, only table2 export is fired. How can I manage that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you `exit` at the end of your export scripts...!? Also, you can't output several CSV files in one response, it'll all become one single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know "exit" kills both child- and parent-script - that's the cause why you only get the first table exported in a csv. Use "return" instead to continue.